# Accessing function documentation

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, function, documentation

Is there a way to access docstrings in Bash? How does one include a docstring in a function's definition in Bash?

More specifically how do I add and access docstrings to the following function?

```bsh
    funky() {
    echo "Violent and funky!"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "Bash's equivalent of Python's docstrings" I'm afraid I have to disappoint you that there is no such thing.

However.. I must say that implementing an equivalent of the "docstrings" feature *would* make for a very interesting homework in order to learn Bash's programmable-completion facility along with how to override a builtin command such as `help` to display either such "docstrings" or the normal builtin `help`'s output.

Answer (score 2):

Though sub-optimal, the following method works fine in a pinch:

```bash
declare -A fundocs_;
doc() { fundocs_[$1]=$2; }
help_doc() { echo "$1:  ${fundocs_[$1]}"; }

doc hi_from_fun "Send a short greeting"
hi_from_fun() { echo "Hi there"; }

help_doc hi_from_fun
```

will print documentation as follows:

```
hi_from_fun:  Send a short greeting
```

Note that the first argument must match the function name, making this method error-prone.  To avoid errors in the long run, it is possible to define a function's documentation inside the body, as follows:

```bash
docd() { :; }  # dummy function
# for debug trap based documentation, redefined later
#  should be called with documentation as arguments
#  near the top of function body

fun2() {
    echo "Hi, I'm fun2 without documentation, just doing my job."; }

fun3() {
    docd "says hi3"
    echo "Hi, I'm fun3 with documentation, doing useful work." ; }

fun4() {
    docd "says hi4"
    echo "hi from fun4 doing other useful work"; }
```

A temporary DEBUG trap can be used to access the document string, as follows:

```bash
docd_() {
    # process args as documentation string
    # and return from nth level caller
    local n=${1:-2}; shift; local c=${FUNCNAME[$n]}
    local f=${1:-'echo $c: $@'}; shift
    [ -n "$c" -a "$c" != source ] && {
        eval $f
        trap "trap - DEBUG; return 2" DEBUG; } }

pdoc() {  #  redefine docd to call docd_ defined above
    docd() {
        docd_ 2 "" $@
        # default action: echo "function_name:  document_string"
    }

    for f; do $f; done  # arguments are function names

    docd() { : # so that the next call to function runs normally
    }
 }
```

such that

```bash
pdoc fun1 fun4 fun2 docd_ fun3
```

will print:

```
bash: fun1: command not found
fun4: says hi4
Hi, I'm fun2 without documentation, just doing my job.
fun3: says hi3
```

You may want to capture the documentation in an array for building a menu.
For example:

```bash
prepdoc() {  # collect documentation of functions
    declare -Ag fundocs_
    docd() { docd_ 2 "fundocs_[\$c]=\"\$*\"" $@; }
    for f; do $f; done
    docd() { :; }
    declare -p fundocs_; }

prepdoc fun1 fun4 fun2 docd_ fun3
```

will print:

```
bash: fun1: command not found
Hi, I'm fun2 without documentation, just doing my job.
declare -A fundocs_='([fun3]="says hi3" [fun4]="says hi4" )'
```

where the nonexistent fun1 and undocumented fun2 are exceptions, should normally be avoided during the scan, but were included above just to demonstrate what happens when called.

Finally, verify that each function can do its normal job:

```bash
for f in fun1 fun4 fun2 docd_ fun3; do $f; done
```

and will print:

```
bash: fun1: command not found
hi from fun4 doing other useful work
Hi, I'm fun2 without documentation, just doing my job.
Hi, I'm fun3 with documentation, doing useful work.
```